# TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h Not Found

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, twitter-fabric

I have implemented Fabric and Twitter Kit for my Cordova project to implement Twitter login. Works perfectly in Android Studio. While importing the Fabric and Twitter kit to Xcode. i get `"Twitter.h/TwitterKit"` not found error on build.

I have followed every single step Fabric told me to. Included Run build script also. But still it shows `Twitterkit` not found. Any way to check or solution for this?

here is the screenshot:

[image: Cordova showing TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h Not Found]

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem in an obj-c project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import like this. #import`<TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h>`